# Mongoose Populate - array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

can someone please help me with population of this schema? I need to populate array of Staff by their userId.

```
var PlaceSchema = new Schema ({
    name:       { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    permalink:  { type: String },
    country:    { type: String, required: true },
         ...long story :D...
    staff:      [staffSchema],
    admins:     [adminSchema],
    masterPlace:{ type: Boolean },
    images:     []

});

var staffSchema = new Schema ({
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account' },
    role: { type: Number }
});

var adminSchema = new Schema ({
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account'}
})

var Places = mongoose.model('Places', PlaceSchema);
```

I tried to use this query, but without success.

```
Places.findOne({'_id' : placeId}).populate('staff.userId').exec(function(err, doc){
    console.log(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polpulation is intended as a method for **"pulling in"** information from the related models in the collection. So rather than specifying a related field "directly", instead *reference* the related fields so the document *appears* to have all of those *sub-documents* embedded in the response:

```
Places.findOne({'_id' : placeId}).populate('staff','_id')
    .exec(function(err, doc){
    console.log(doc);
});
```

The second argument just returns the field that you want. So it "filters" the response.

There is more information on [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) in the documentation.